# Правильный выбор блока с GET-запросом

Tags: php

У меня есть файл `add.php`, который содержит следующий код:

```
switch ($_GET['type']) {

   case 'news':
       echo 'тут форма добавления новости';
   break;

   case 'page':
       echo 'тут форма добавления страницы';
   break; 

}

echo "text1";
```

Нужно сделать так: если мы просто зашли `add.php`, то выводится, к примеру, "`text1`"; если мы зашли `add.php?type=news`, то "`text1`" выводиться уже не должен, а должно
"тут форма добавления новости" также с `add.php?type=page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкции switch предусмотрено действие по умолчанию. Аналог команды условия else

```
switch($_GET['type']){
    case 'news':
        echo 'тут форма добавления новости';
    break;
    case 'page':
        echo 'тут форма добавления страницы';
    break;
    default:
        echo "text1";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте параметр `default`:

```
switch($_GET['type'];) {
    case 'news':
        echo 'тут форма добавления новости';
    break;
    case 'page':
        echo 'тут форма добавления страницы';
    break;
    default:
        echo "text1";
    break;
}
```

Специальный вид конструкции `case -- default`. Сюда управление попадает тогда, когда не сработал ни один из других операторов case.
[Вот подробный мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Я знаю что есть такая конструкция default: но он  не подойдет в данном случае мне что всю страницу (весь код HTML/PHP) в эту конструкцию вставлять? это будет глупо, я слышал есть другие способы.

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать так:

    $nekiy_text = '';
    
    switch($_GET['type'];) {
        case 'news':
            echo 'тут форма добавления новости';
        break;
        case 'page':
            echo 'тут форма добавления страницы';
        break;
        default:
            $nekiy_text = "text1";
        break;
    }
    ...некий код....
    $nekiy_text; //в нужном месте вставляете переменную. Если она пуста, то ничего не изменится, а если в ней что-то есть, то вы получите желаемый результат!

Пробуйте.

В идеале напишите свой код на ideone.com, и я посмотрю, что у вас там.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Либо скажите, что у вас не получается и я вам отвечу.